# Sympy solveset() returns ConditionSet() when it should be returning a numerical answer

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am using sympy to solve the following rather complex equation:

[image: eqn]

I want a single numerical solution, which has to be positive.

my script is as follows:

```
from sympy import *

def CalcScaleParam_solveset(mode, percentage, Xmin, Xmax):

    s = Symbol('s', positive=True)

    eqn = (1 / 2 * erf((log(Xmax) - (log(mode) + s ** 2)) / (sqrt(2) * s)) - (1 / 2 * erf((log(Xmin) - (log(mode) + s ** 2)) / (sqrt(2) * s)))) - 0.95

    sigma = solveset(eqn, s, domain=S.Reals)

    print(sigma)


CalcScaleParam_solveset(2, 0.95, 1, 4)
```

I am using arbitrary numbers for `mode`, `percentage`, `Xmin` and `Xmax`

This returns

`ConditionSet(s, Eq(0.5*erf(-sqrt(2)*(-s**2 - log(2))/(2*s)) + 0.5*erf(sqrt(2)*(-s**2 - log(2) + log(4))/(2*s)) - 0.95, 0), (-oo, oo))`

Which means that there is only a partial solution to the equation.

However I know that this is not true because plotting the equation with `plot(eqn, (s, 0, 1))` shows that there is a single positive solution, as shown in the following image:

[image: The plotted function]

I looked for much bigger ranges and and there does not seem to be any other point at which the function is equal to 0. matlab is able to find a single numerical solution to the same equation.

It is worth mentioning that using the sympy `solve()` function (outdated according to the docs) instead of `solveset()` returns `NotImplementedError: multiple generators`

How do I get the value where it is equal to 0 as shown in the graph? Is it outside the capacity of sympy 1.0?

As you can see I specified that the answer should be a positive real number in my code, so I don't understand why it only finds a partial solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think `solveset` is trying to find a symbolic solution. If you only want a numerical solution, I think `findroot` is the function to use.

Comment: You can use `sympy.nsolve`, which is a wrapper around `mpmath.findroot`. Or use one of the root finding functions from [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).